Maidenhead installer QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.36.3-2.msi does not auto update QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.36.3-1.msi
I am trying to upgrade to Maidenhead 3.36.3.2, and I have 3.36.3.1 installed
error:
Another version is already installed. you need remove existing product
both the versions have same GUID:
{B2CAE8D8-7081-1014-A5EF-C954DBC4DF28}
both install with same version - 3.36.3
OS- win 10 x64
Installer- https://download.osgeo.org/qgis/windows/?C=M&O=D
both versions work fine independently.
parameters used to test: "ALLUSERS=1 INSTALLDESKTOPSHORTCUTS=0"
What is the solution?

would completely remove the old version and re-install.

Thanks for responding @Mapperz
